# Showing elements based on ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying not to render part of my code. I want to render it only when answer is correct/not correct. At the beginning only question and answers should be displayed. React renders false argument "you are wrong". State is set to null. I checked and null doesnt equal false nor true. Why does it renders anything? How to not render anything until user chooses wrong/correct answer? Code:

```
export default class QuoteApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       index: 0,
       isCorrect: null
    }
  }

  confirmAnswer = () => {
      this.setState({
          index: this.state.index + 1
      })
  }

  handleClick = (e, index) => {
    if (e.target.textContent === data[index].name) {
      this.setState({
        isCorrect: true
      }) 
      } else {
        this.setState({
          isCorrect: false
        })
    }
  }

  render() {
      const { index, isCorrect } = this.state
      console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div className="QuoteApp">
        <div className={ (this.state.isCorrect ? 'hide' : '') }>
          <Quote index={index}/>
          <Answers index={index}
                 handleClick={this.handleClick}
                 />
        </div>
        {isCorrect ?
        <h1>you're right</h1>
        :
        <h1>you're wrong</h1>}
        <button onClick={this.confirmAnswer}>Confirm</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want

you're right
:
you're wrong
to be gone till user interaction

Comment: `isCorrect === null ? <h1 /> : isCorrect ? <h1>you're right</h1> : <h1>you're wrong</h1>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using && operator. You will see you're right or wrong only on user interaction

```
{isCorrect !== null && isCorrect && 
        <h1>you're right</h1>}
{isCorrect !== null && !isCorrect && 
        <h1>you're wrong</h1>}
```

Do something like below to hide Quote/Answer when user chooses answer

Using && operator

```
    {isCorrect === null && <div className={ (this.state.isCorrect ? 'hide' : '') }>
      <Quote index={index}/>
      <Answers index={index}
             handleClick={this.handleClick}
             />
    </div>}
```

OR ternary operator

```
 {isCorrect === null ? <div className={ (this.state.isCorrect ? 'hide' : '') }>
      <Quote index={index}/>
      <Answers index={index}
             handleClick={this.handleClick}
             />
    </div> : null}
```

Comment: I have another question related to that code. Whats the proper/best way to hide Quote and Answers components based on users interaction? For now it works fine only when the answer is true, but for false i haven't found an answer. When user chooses answer i want to Quote/Answer component be hidden and only div with correct/false info be displayed. What's the easiest way?

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Comment: Thanks, now i have to understand that so i can implement it in further projects.

Comment: yeah you will be heavily using these two operators in react applns. You will get to know more. Keep learning

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
{ isCorrect !== null && 
  ( isCorrect ? <h1>you're right</h1> : <h1>you're wrong</h1> )
  || '' // To make sure we don't print boolean value in the UI
}
```

The `&&` condition will will satisfy the `isCorrect` return value. If it is `null`, then it will not go ahead. We're wrapping them in a parentheses because we would like to execute the code inside that only if `isCorrect` is not `null`.

Comment: he don't wants you're wrong to be displayed by default